# Accessing an existing control on Outlook ribbon

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, visual-studio-2008-sp1

I want to add a CommandBarButton to an existing CommandBarPopup that displays in an Outlook MailItem compose ribbon.  (Ribbon ID: Microsoft.Outlook.Mail.Compose)

I found code that shows me how to add a new CommandBarButton to a CommandBarPopup, but I can't find out how to get a reference to the CommandBarPopup. This is an existing Popup on the ribbon, not a custom popup.

Answer (score 0):

Command bars are not used any longer in Office applications (Outlook in your case). Starting from Outlook 2007 the new UI is used instead - Ribbon UI (aka Fluent UI). You can read more about the UI in the following series of articles in MSDN:

1. [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.12).aspx)
2. [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
3. [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: I do not believe those articles are appropriate for this question. They explain how to make your own customizations such as adding control's etc to a ribbon, but do not tell you how to modify attributes for built-in controls on the ribbon, if even possible. My understanding is that the built-in controls are commandbars. but I could be wrong.

Comment: What office version are you talking about? The articles describe the New UI which is called Ribbon (Fluent).

Comment: Office 2010 and 2013. Yes, I am using the New UI/Ribbon (Fluent) stuff in this article. But article does not describe how to access build-in controls if even possible.

Comment: What exactly do you need to implement? If you need to paste the built-in control into a custom UI you need to specify the idMso value of the built-in control.